# Importing a VB6 dll into a c# project

Tags: c#, .net, dll, vb6, interop

I'm trying to use a object made id VB6 into my c# project, but I don't have the VB6 source code. A did this steps:

1) register the mail.dll (thats a VB6 dll);

2) add the reference that appears on COM;

3) import to my code.

I create an object. But when I tried to call the method SendMailSMTP from this dll I got this error:
ActiveX component can't create object(429)

This error is common when the DLL is not registered. But a registered with success. 
Is there any other way to create this VB6 dll with correct interoperability ?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SMTPMail;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
   {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string msgRetorno = "";
            clsSMTPmail smtpMail = new clsSMTPmail();
            string from = "test@test.com.br";
            string to = "test@test.com.br"; ;
            string cc = "";
            string subject = "teste subject";
            string corpo = "Mensagem de teste";

            string profileSMTP = "";
            string passwordSMTP = "";

            try 
            { 
                msgRetorno = smtpMail.SendMailSMTP(from, to, cc, subject, corpo, profileSMTP, passwordSMTP, null); 
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                msgRetorno = e.InnerException.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might need the ``[STAThread]`` attribute.

Comment: It sounds like your `mail.dll` in turns depends on perhaps another dll that also needs to be registered.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use the built-in `System.Mail` namespace to send email via SMTP?

Comment: First they asked me to use this way because is the company standard. But now they agree with using the System.Mail. Thks for the answers! But the problem was like @sstan said. The mail.dll use a dll that I don't have. But the way that this dll were imported cover the results from Dependecy Walker.. that I used to find the dependencies.